# Minimize a $C^1$ function subject to convex constraint set using feasible directions.

Tags: optimization

Let $X$ be a convex set. Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ a $C^1$ function.
The idea is to minimize f subject to $x \in X$.

Let $x^* \in X$ be a point such that
$$\nabla f(x^*)^T (x-x^*) \geq 0$$
for all $x \in X$.
Then can I conclude that $x^*$ is a local minimum?
If not, is there an obvious counterexample?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple counter example in one dimension:

$X = [0, 2]$,
$f(x) = -(x-1)^2$,
$\nabla f(x) = -2(x-1)$

$\nabla f(x^*)^T(x-x^*) = -2(x^*-1)(x-x^*)$

Let $x^* = 1$. Then clearly the condition is zero for any choice of $x \in X$.

However $x^*$ is not a local minimum, it is a local maximum.

Comment: You are correct, but I was thinking in the case $$\nabla f(x^*)^T (x-x^*)>0\,.$$